# Is there any supported Bluetooth profile which is used in iOS except 6 profiles(HFP, PBAP, A2DP, AVRCP, PAN, HID)?

Tags: ios5, bluetooth, profile, spp

Is there any supported Bluetooth profile which is used in iOS5 except 6 profiles(HFP, PBAP, A2DP, AVRCP, PAN, HID)?

Can I use SPP(Serial-Port profile) as developing iPhone app?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Serial Port Profile(SPP),either you need to apply for MFi or use MFi certified devices to communicate with iOS.

Here is the MFi link

https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

In addition to the above Profiles MAP is supported from iOS6.

You can find the supported profile under this link

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647